# NSTableRowView + Accessibility

Tags: swift, macos, accessibility

I've been migrating my code to Swift and now I'm trying to modernize the UI by switching to view-based table views (OS X). With the cell-based tableview, providing accessibility title, etc. was as easy as overriding the `func accessibilityTitle()` on the cell (it was a subclass of `NSTextFieldCell`) - but unfortunately, with `NSTableRowView`, it's not as easy.

I've overridden pretty much everything I can think of, but the VoiceOver still reads "Table View Cell" and nothing else. The overridden methods don't even get called.

I've also overridden `func isAccessibilityElement() -> Bool`, `func isAccessibilitySelectorAllowed(selector: Selector) -> Bool`, `func accessibilityIsAttributeSettable(attribute: String) -> Bool` to always return true. These methods don't even get called.

I've also tried for the cell to conform to `NSAccessibilityStaticText`, but that's not possible in Swift, so I've tried a hack, overriding `conformsToProtocol(_:)`, but that never gets called either.

Another thing I've tried was overriding `func respondsToSelector(_:)` to check what selectors is the runtime checking, but alas nothing helpful gets checked.

Is there anyone who's tried solving this? All I want is to supply VoiceOver with a custom string to be read out...

Comment: I just tried VoiceOver on my custom NSTableCellViews and they all work out of the box. I'm not doing anything for accessibility. My cell view has 3 NSTextFields and VoiceOver reads all of them out with no problems.

Comment: @rocky But in case you want to have a custom title, this is a valid question.